# How to import 12-bit TIFF image

Tags: import, image, tiff-format

I have a CMOS camera which records images at 12 bit resolution. The camera software allows to save them as 12-bit TIFs. However, *Mathematica* cannot import this:

```
Import["12_bit.tif", "BitDepth"] (* -> 12 *)
img = Import["12_bit.tif"] (* -> $Failed *)
```

> `Import::unsup`: Unsupported type of TIFF file.

**How can I read 12-bit TIF images?**

Here is the original image: http://tinyurl.com/jyg6jwm

I also can save camera images as 16 Bit TIFs.

**Comparison of image size** on my computer (Win 10 Pro, NTFS):

12 Bit TIF:

Size: 6.299.794 Bytes

Size on SSD: 6.303.744 Bytes

16 Bit TIF:

Size: 8.396.946 Bytes

Size on SSD: 8.400.896 Bytes

Comment: You might have to convert it to a 16-bit pixel format in some other software before you can import it. Or, assuming that this is a scientific camera, you can save it in some other format (such as FITS).

Comment: I tried the same as you.
Also Photoshop CC 2015 can read 12 Bit TIFs and can save them as 16 BIT TIFs ... but I think this is a task which should also be implemented in Mathematica (if not yet possible)!

Comment: Perhaps you might like to submit it as a feature request to WRI. I'm not sure how common are 12-bit TIFF files, because the TIFF 6.0 specification seems not to actually define how a 12-bit file should be produced--there are no 12-bit field types defined. Thus, implementations could vary. It seems that LibTIFF (and thus MATLAB) does not support it either. TIFF is not necessarily the best choice of format; I tend to avoid it unless others ask me to use it.

Comment: Our SEM kicks out 12bit TIFF by default. I changed the settings to 16bit to avoid this, but have posted a workaround below that may or may not be useful for you.

Comment: shot in the dark but see if `Import[ .. "Data"]` works

Comment: If the 16-bit TIFF just contains 12-bit data with the first four bits zero, can't you apply LZW compression to achieve almost the same file size as the uncompressed 12-bit TIFF?

Comment: Hi,I very need your original image with 12 bit for a test,but your link is lapse.Would you provide to me? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the **answer from Wolfram Technical Support**

> 12-bit TIFF files are not currently supported by Mathematica. Our
>   developers are interested in supporting this format, however, and I
>   have filed a suggestion on your behalf. I have also included your
>   contact information so that you can be notified if this gets
>   implemented.

Comment: 12-bit TIFF files are supported in Mathematica 10.4.

Answer (score 5):

If you're command line friendly, one possible workaround is to use `imagemagick` or one of the various `libtiff` command line tools to turn your image into 16-bit, viz.---

```
Import["12_bit.tif"] (* $Failed *)
Run["/usr/local/bin/convert 12_bit.tif -depth 16 16_bit.tif"] (* 0 *)
Import["16_bit.tif"] (* sweet sweet success *)
```

On the Mac, I have `imagemagick` and friends installed via `homebrew` for these sorts of situations.